# Want to create a form with each option having own submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to create a form like the attached image. So far, [here is my progress](https://codepen.io/TouseefQ/pen/LYmRXad).

```js
function gotoTask() {
    var message = document.getElementById("goto").value;
    goto_message.innerHTML = message;
}

function waitTask() {
    var message = document.getElementById("wait").value;
    wait_message.innerHTML = message;
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
}
div.input_fields {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #17375e;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.task_window {
    width: 50%
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid #17375e;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

select {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

button {
    background-color: #17375e;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="input_fields">
  <label for="goto">Go to</label>

  <select id="goto">
    <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
    <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
    <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
    <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="gotoTask()">OK</button>
</div>
<div class="input_fields">
  <label for="wait">Wait for</label>

  <select id="wait">
    <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
    <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
    <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
    <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="waitTask()">OK</button>
</div>

<div class="task_window">
  Task: <span id="goto_message"></span> <span id="wait_message"></span>
  <button type="submit" onclick="pushTask()">OK</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Basically it has several option inputs and each input have its own submit button which when clicked shows the selected option at the bottom of the page. My question is do I have to create a number of forms to make this happen or I can do this within one single form? Or is there any other way to do this altogether?

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything? please share here

Comment: It depends. You may not even need to use forms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This is far too vague and open-ended for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: There are probably about 20 ways you could implement this.

Comment: Please add the JS you tried in the snippet I made you so your attempt is visible here at SO

Comment: And change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: You only need forms if you want to use the submit event of each form. It seems you do NOT need forms since the click event on the buttons are just fine as they are now. IF you wrap in a form, you MUST change to type="button" or add an event.preventDefault() to each handler

Comment: @mplungjan I have added the JS and CSS code to run the snippet. This is me first time using stackoverflow so I might not be aware of some of the functionality of how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I finally did it.

```js
function createTaskFn(label, messageId) {
  var task_value = document.getElementById(messageId).value;
  var task_label = document.getElementById(label).textContent;
  if (task_value) {
    final_task.innerHTML += `<span class="task_box">${task_label}: ${task_value} <a onclick="clearTask(this)"><img src="cross.png"></a></span>`;
  }
}

function clearTask(e) {
  e.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

div.input_fields {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #17375e;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input_fields label {
  width: 50%;
}

.input_fields select {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#final_task {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.task_window {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #17375e;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.task_box {
  border: 1px solid #17375e;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

span.task_box img {
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.task_btn {
  background-color: #17375e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="input_fields">
    <label for="goto" id="goto_label">Go to</label>

    <select id="goto">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
      <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
      <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
      <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTaskFn('goto_label', 'goto')" class="task_btn">
        OK
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="input_fields">
    <label for="wait" id="wait_label">Wait for</label>

    <select id="wait">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
      <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
      <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
      <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTaskFn('wait_label', 'wait')" class="task_btn">
        OK
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="input_fields">
    <label for="pickup" id="pickup_label">Pick-up load</label>

    <select id="pickup">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
      <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
      <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
      <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTaskFn('pickup_label', 'pickup')" class="task_btn">
        OK
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="input_fields">
    <label for="wait" id="dropoff_label">Dropp-off load</label>

    <select id="dropoff">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
      <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
      <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
      <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTaskFn('dropoff_label','dropoff')" class="task_btn">
        OK
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="input_fields">
    <label for="charge" id="charge_label">Charge</label>

    <select id="charge">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
      <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
      <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
      <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTaskFn('charge_label', 'charge')" class="task_btn">
        OK
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="input_fields">
    <label for="repeat" id="repeat_label">Repeat</label>

    <select id="repeat">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
      <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
      <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
      <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTaskFn('repeat_label', 'repeat')" class="task_btn">
        OK
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="input_fields">
    <label for="stop" id="stop_label">Stop</label>

    <select id="stop">
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Place 1">Place 1</option>
      <option value="Place 2">Place 2</option>
      <option value="Place 3">Place 3</option>
      <option value="Place 4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTaskFn('stop_label', 'stop')" class="task_btn">
        OK
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="task_window">
    Task:
    <div id="final_task"></div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="pushTask()" class="task_btn">OK</button>
  </div>
</body>
```